# Overriding with generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding, abstract-class

Consider the following abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractAssembler {

    public abstract <T extends AbstractValue> void transform(T value);

}
```

and the following extension:

```
public class MyAssembler extends AbstractAssembler {

    @Override
    public void transform(MyValue value) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

With `MyValue`

```
public class MyValue extends AbstractValue {

    // ...

}
```

Eclipse tells me:
The method transform(MyValue) of type MyAssembler must override or implement a supertype method

Why does this not work?

Comment: Just use `AbstractAssembler<T extends AbstractValue>`, `public abstract void transform(T value);` and `public class MyAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<MyValue>`.

Comment: @Tom you should post it as an answer...

Comment: Imagine the following situation: `AbstractAssembler a = new MyAssembler(); a.transform(new MyOtherValue());`... What is the second line supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `transform()` method must override the generic abstract `transform()` method in the super class, i.e. you should have something like:

```
public class MyAssembler extends AbstractAssembler {

    @Override
    public <T extends AbstractValue> void transform(T value) {

    }
}
```

If you want to invoke it with an actual type (e.g. `MyValue`) you should do:

```
MyValue value = new MyValue();
new MyAssembler().transfer(value);
```

where explicitly specifying the type-parameter (`new MyAssembler().<MyValue>transfer(value);`) is optional, as it will be inferred by the compiler.

---

If you however wish `MyAssember`'s `transform` method to work *only* with `MyValue`, then you should do:

```
public class MyAssembler extends AbstractAssembler<MyValue> {

    @Override
    public void transform(MyValue value) {

    }
}
```